# How can I use antialiasing in Gnuplot to make an gif?

Tags: animation, gnuplot, gif, animated-gif, antialiasing

For example, What do I need to add to this code to activate the antialiasing?

```
set terminal gif animate delay 5 size 400, 250
set output "example.gif"

a = 0

do for [i=1:100] {
a = a + 0.1
plot sin(x + a)
}
```

[image: example.gif]

Do I need to change some of the files of the gnuplot folder? I'm using the 5.2 Windows version of gnuplot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the terminal `pngcairo` that has antialiasing to create separate png files:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 400, 250

a = 0

do for [i=1:100] {
set output sprintf("%.3d.png",i)
plot sin(x + a)
a = a + 0.1
}
```

Then you can assemble a gif file, for example, with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s `convert`:

```
convert -delay 5 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif
```

[image]